# Button with no hWnd

Tags: c#, winapi, spy++

Good evening folks,

I'm building a simple application (A) that sends Strings to a textbox of another application (B). I was able to this step, but afterwards I'd like to automatically press a button placed just under the textbox. The problem is that I can't get the Handle of the Button; using "Window Detective"(similiar to Spy++), I see only the textboxes (called "TEdit", see the attachments) and no Buttons!. I'd like to add also that there's no only a Button but 3!! So, how could I press a specific Button? Is there another chance to get the Handle?

[Program "target"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDYwV.png)

[Window Detective screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqiJx.png)

Comment: Use System.Windows.Automation.

Comment: @andlabs Sadly this app won't yield to Automation

Comment: @DavidHeffernan well that was sooner to find something like that than I expected :| I've never used VCL; is there any advantage to TSpeedButton over TButton?

Comment: @andlabs Simple way to stop somebody automating your app or it being accessible...  ;-)  I think the main reason is the glyph. All rendered irrelevant by modern incarnations where plain BUTTON wrapper, the windowed TButton, can do all of that and be themed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the class name `TEdit` that's a VCL application probably coded in Delphi. The buttons are likely `TSpeedButton` and non-windowed. You won't be able to send them messages and they are not automatable.

Faced with this your best hope of success is to fake input. Fake the mouse click at the appropriate location on the form. It's not pretty but there's little option.