# Send mouse click to specific x y

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm building an app that should send a mouse click on another app (and I don't have the source code). On the web there are several solutions but no one satisfied my requirements. I have to send the click on a button but I don't have the hWnd (that's because it's a "only graphic" button [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39730027/button-with-no-hwnd?noredirect=1#comment66761081_39730027)). What I need exactly is to send a click to a specific (x,y), on a button with no handle, in a window **not on top**. Thanks in advance!

Comment: For sending message to the app you have to know its HWND.

Comment: You could likely get away with sending the click to the HWND at that specific point in that app, or at worst, to the HWND of the top-level window (but again, I don't know how VCL works).

Comment: Ultimately, there has to be **any** HWND at those coordinates. Whether or not the HWND is the actual button, or the button's parent, or its parent, or so on does not matter. The app will receive the click on whatever `HWND` it actually is, and it is then the responsibility of the app to translate and delegate the click as needed to whatever the actual control is, whether windowed or graphical.

Comment: If you need to automate a GUI that isn't visible, you need to go with *UI Automation*.

Comment: @IInspectable already suggested that; see the linked question.

Comment: but not possible to do (for what I understood)